# ruby task scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scheduled-tasks

Are there any good and easy to use ruby task schedulers? I just need to call an external api on a custom schedule per user. So I would prefer a lightweight framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Rufus](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) seems to be a popular task scheduler for Rails.

or checkout [delayed job](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), which is also very popular.

Comment: `delayed_job` is not a *scheduler* per-se. Also, please link to the [delayed_job page](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). And rufus is great - it is very easy to setup and use.

Comment: Also edited mine to link to delayed job page. Thanks Zabba.