# How do I call a function at fixed intervals?

Tags: ruby, timer

I want to call a particular function every five minutes.

I  accumulate data in a string variable and then I want a function to process it.

How do I do it in Ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby task scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369459/ruby-task-scheduler)

Comment: Anushka! Please read the [How to ask a good question manual](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Or my compiled [Newbie Manual](http://grahn.us/projects/stack-overflow.php)

Comment: You can also try the gem [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler):

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.in '5m' do
  your_method(args)
end

scheduler.join
  # let the current thread join the scheduler thread
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one example by providing a poison to enable/disable your function calls in another thread:

```
poison = false

t = Thread.new do
  loop do
    break if poison
    your_method(args)
    sleep(5.minutes)
    redo
  end
end
# uncomment the next line if this is your main thread
#t.join
```